# Applying CSS style to table cell when hovered over

Tags: html, css

I have a table that has a class, and some `td` elements inside of it. What is the correct CSS to give a hover effect on `td`s which are part of a table with some particular class?

```
<table class='some_class'>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>321</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What's the right CSS? This is not working:

```
> .some_class td:hover { some style }
```

Comment: What OS? What browser? Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Bootstrap can do this like : <span role="button">hi</span> source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34243399/7791423

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put this in your css file

```
body {
background-color: #ccc;
}

table.some_style td {
background-color: #0f0;
}

table.some_style td:hover {
background-color: #06c;
}
```

and this as your table

```
<table class="some_style">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>column one</th>
                    <th>column two</th>
                                <th>column three</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>data one</td>
                    <td>data two</td>
                                <td>data three</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: @David, I've updated the code above. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Can you post your code here so I can take a look. Here is my full code, try this http://pastebin.com/hY9GGJKG

Comment: There were my mistakes in first try. your code works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me
    
    table td:hover{
        background : red;
    }

```
<table class='some_class'>
<tr>   
<td>123</td>
<td>321</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**I think your code should work also, maybe you didn't include css correctly , which browser do you use ???**