# Change cursor to hand when mouse goes over a row in table

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

How do I change the cursor pointer to hand when my mouse goes over a `<tr>` in a `<table>`

```
<table class="sortable" border-style:>
  <tr>
    <th class="tname">Name</th><th class="tage">Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td class="tname">Jennifer</td><td class="tage">24</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="tname">Kate</td><td class="tage">36</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="tname">David</td><td class="tage">25</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="tname">Mark</td><td class="tage">40</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For an interactive code snippet check my answer

Answer (score 411, accepted):

You can do this with CSS actually.

```
.sortable tr {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 232):

I've searched bootstrap styles a bit and found this:

```
[role=button]{cursor:pointer}
```

So I assume you can get what you want with:

```
<span role="button">hi</span>
```

Comment: It was nice for bootstrap aficionados, but the question does not involve any front framework, so I don't understand why this answer is relevant with the question (even if the answer is great)

Comment: @Hooli as of 6-2018 this is post is now the top result when searching "bootstrap change icon to pointer on hover."

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Just tested and it most definitely DOES work with BS 4

Comment: **Important:** Do not add `role="button"` when you want to add `style="cursor:pointer;"`. First off, your element depends on that CSS being defined elsewhere (and not being overridden elsewhere else) and, most importantly, you are ***misusing the `role` attribute***, simply because most users do not need it. Note most screen readers allow iterating through `[role=button]` elements giving web accessibility challenged users the ability to quickly go through all the page buttons. Don't make them have to go through each of the table's rows to get to the footer links!

Answer (score 83):

The easiest way I've found is to add

```
style="cursor: pointer;"
```

to your  tags.

Answer (score 30):

Add `cursor: pointer` to your css.

Answer (score 21):

I added this to my `style.css` to manage cursor options:

```
.cursor-pointer {cursor: pointer;}
.cursor-crosshair {cursor: crosshair;}
.cursor-eresize {cursor: e-resize;}
.cursor-move {cursor: move;}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use the style `cursor: pointer;` in the CSS for the element you want the cursor to change on.

In your case, you would use (in your .css file):

```
.sortable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Example with styles inline:

```html
<table>
  <tr> <td style="cursor: pointer;">mouse me over: pointer</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td style="cursor: wait;">mouse me over: wait</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td style="cursor: zoom-in;">mouse me over: zoom-in</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 12):

For compatibility with IE < 6 use this style in that order:

```
.sortable:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

But remember that IE < 7 supports `:hover` pseudoclass only with `<a>` element.

Answer (score 10):

Use the CSS *cursor* property like so:

```
<table class="sortable">
  <tr>
    <th class="tname">Name</th><th class="tage">Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="cursor: pointer;"><td class="tname">Jennifer</td><td class="tage">24</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="tname">Kate</td><td class="tage">36</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="tname">David</td><td class="tage">25</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="tname">Mark</td><td class="tage">40</td></tr>
</table>
```

Of course you should put the style into your CSS file and apply it to the class.

Answer (score 4):

Using css

```
table tr:hover{cursor:pointer;} /* For all tables*/
table.sortable tr:hover{cursor:pointer;} /* only for this one*/
```

Answer (score 3):

for just a standard the above solutions work, but if you are using datatables, you have to override the default datatatables.css settings and add the following code to custom css, In the code below row-select is the class that I added on datatables as shown in the html.

```
table.row-select.dataTable tbody td
{
cursor: pointer;    
}
```

And you html will look as below:

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions1" dt-columns="dtColumns1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover row-select"  id="datatable"></table>
```

Comment: What above solution?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this in 2023. Adding `btn` to the class worked for me in a `navbar-nav>li nav-item>a`.